# Two column equation block with vertical separator

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, multicolumn

I have seen various examples in text books and web pages (like [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A)) of two column equation blocks, where the left column has some equation(s) and the right column has some explanation on variable meanings and/or other things. I wish to split an equation like below into two columns with a vertical separator in between without involving minipage, Tikz, and other fancy stuff like that. Seems like something that should be in common demand. But I cannot find an example of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\begin{flalign}
z &= \frac{R\left(S_2 − S_1\right)}{2\left(S_1 + S_2\right)} + \frac{R}{2}\\
text{\scriptsize{where}}
    &\text{\scriptsize{ $R$ is the camera range,}} \nonumber\\
    &\text{\scriptsize{$S_1$ is the amount of the light pulse received, and}} \nonumber\\
    &\text{\scriptsize{$S_2$ is the amount of the light pulse blocked \cite{medina1992three} \nonumber.
}}
\end{flalign}
```

I am using the `scrbook` documentclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `|` delimiter and an array

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
    z = \frac{R(S_2 − S_1)}{2(S_1 + S_2)} + \frac{R}{2} \quad \left|\quad\begin{array}{r@{\ }>$l<$}
    R   & is the amount of the light pulse received, and\\
    S_1 & is the amount of the light pulse received, and\\
    S_2 & is the amount of the light pulse blocked [MED92]\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    z = \frac{R(S_2 − S_1)}{2(S_1 + S_2)} + \frac{R}{2} \quad \left|\quad\begin{array}{>$l<$}
    $R$ is the amount of the light pulse received, and\\
    $S_1$ is the amount of the light pulse received, and\\
    $S_2$ is the amount of the light pulse blocked [MED92]\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! Actually, I wanted to have the text side-by-side with the equation, and the visible vertical line between the equation and the text, not between the 'where' and the rest of the text :)

Comment: That indeed does it! Thank you very much! I wish there were a less hackish way, but this works too!

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta Then you will like my completely revised answer. I got your question wrong in the first case.

Comment: May I request one small modification? What would happen if there are 2 subequations?